# vscode: Using the proposed API cannot find "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vscode/master/src/vs/vscode.proposed.d.ts"

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use registerInlineCompletionItemProvider proposed API. I'm following the instructions in https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_58 and here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/inline-completions. Both of them ask to copy https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vscode/master/src/vs/vscode.proposed.d.ts to your local directory, but that file doesn't exist. Also when I follow the instructions to install the extension I always get an error because it doesn't exist:

```
Downloading vscode.proposed.d.ts
To:   /home/gussand/vscode-extension-samples/inline-completions/vscode.proposed.d.ts
From: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vscode/master/src/vs/vscode.proposed.d.ts
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Failed to g./package.json:         "download-api": "vscode-dts dev",
./package.json:         "postdownload-api": "vscode-dts main",
```

anyone have ideas how to solve this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got an answer to this from the VsCode team, and here's what we need to do:

```
1. Install at least version 1.63 of VSCode Insiders. 
2. Change the "enableProposedApi": true to "enabledApiProposals": [ "inlineCompletions" ] in the package.json file. 
3. Run npm i vscode-dts to download the latest version of vscode-dts 
4. Run npx vscode-dts dev.
```

More information here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_63.md#updated-api-proposal-structure

Answer (score 2):

You need https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vscode-dts/vscode.proposed.inlineCompletions.d.ts.

The file was split up 13 days ago in [a4d426a](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/a4d426a1c2ece4222f1343459d31fe948098b2f6), tracked in [#131165](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131165).

Apparently not all docs have been updated.

Comment: Thanks for the location!! How do I modify the postinstall step though to get 'npm install' to finish tough?

Comment: Have you updated https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dts to the latest version, currently 0.3.2? It appears to be updated for the new proposal file layout.

Comment: What's the supported way to update that utility? I installed the new vscode insiders edition yesterday so thought that might get me up to date. thanks!

Comment: I have no idea, sorry, not that deep into VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the question about how to modify the `postinstall` script for the new proposed api's, I'll post this here since it doesn't fit in a comment.  See [proposed-api-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/proposed-api-sample/package.json)

```json
"scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx",
    "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
    "download-api": "vscode-dts dev",
    "postdownload-api": "vscode-dts main",
    "postinstall": "npm run download-api"
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that's the same script we already have in package.json and it errors out because the file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vscode/master/src/vs/vscode.proposed.d.ts" doesn't exist.